# Windows 10 shutdown very slow

Tags: performance, windows-10, shutdown, updates

I installed windows 10 one week ago, it was working fine. But yesterday, after an auto update and installing some Modern UI app, my laptop shutdown became very slow, after the screen was turned off during shutdown, it takes about 30 minutes to shutdown completely (lamp off).

I tried to defrag my hard disk and remove some software, but nothing helped. My C partition is 61/80 GB used.

Comment: install the Windows 10 WPT (part of the Windows 10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and run the commands shown in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/RFRkuc81 share the compressed ETL file

Comment: Fortunally, I removed VirtualBox and its shutdown within 10s again. Thanks :)

Comment: ok, post your finding as answer and mark it as answer. You should also submit the issue to the virtualbox developers: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker

Comment: After uninstall VirtualBox, sometimes my windows shutdown very slow too. I think it's may because install many new software???

Comment: try to capture a shutdown trace with the WPT that includes the slowness

Answer (score 0):

> If you have experienced slow shutdown in Windows 10, you should know
>   that the OS comes with a built-in ability to speed it up. With a few
>   tweaks, you can significantly speed up the shutdown process. Let's see
>   how it can be done.
>
> When you shutdown your PC, Windows 10 is waiting for a response from
>   running applications and services. Depending on how your running apps
>   respond to the shutdown call or exit, Windows can take lots of time,
>   especially if some service or app does not finish its job and exit
>   quickly. In the Registry, there are a few settings which define the
>   time in seconds for which the OS will wait before it forcibly kills
>   running applications to proceed with the shutdown. You can reduce this
>   timeout so Windows 10 will perform a faster shutdown and restart much
>   faster.

Source: http://winaero.com/blog/speed-up-slow-shutdown-in-windows-10/

Comment: Not sure who marked you down.  Good answer - +1